# How to get bound property path for {x:Bind}

Tags: uwp-xaml, winui, winui-3

Using WPF I was able to get the path of a {Binding} bound property through the BindingExpression.  In UWP is there a way to determine which property is bound using the {x:Bind} syntax?  I need to discover which properties are bound to which controls.  I Understand that there is no BindingExpression with {x:Bind}.  Is there another way to map between a control and it's bound property?

Comment: Could you please tell me what the purpose of getting the property which bound to a control? It seems no approach to get the path information when using {x:Bind} extension. If you do want to get the path information, you could also using {Binding} extension in UWP.

Comment: @YanGu - It is necessary to know what property path is bound, to perform validation and then set focus to the input control associated with the invalid data. FYI: the question was general for UWP, but is a use case for Project Reunion 0.5 WinUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{x:Bind} extension is directive executed at design time to generate code to register event handlers and explicitly set the relevant properties, bypassing the {Binding} registration that uses reflection at runtime, so at runtime there is no way to detect or get a handler to the binding statement from an {x:Bind} because there is none.